# C - My code isn't printing the [first] IF statement when I respond with the correct answer - why?

Tags: printing

Guessing game: Please guess the correct number from 1-100. However, when the `secretNumber` is chosen, `printf("You got the secret number correct!");` does not execute.  Why is this?  All other `printf` statements execute.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {

    int secretNumber = 37;
    int guess;
    int guessCount = 0;
    int guessLimit = 3;
    int outOfGuesses = 0;

    printf("Enter a number between 1 and 100: ");
    /* NOT PRINTING */
    scanf("%d", & guess);
    guessCount = guessCount + 1;

    while (guess != secretNumber && outOfGuesses == 0) {

        if (guessCount < guessLimit) {

            if (guess == secretNumber) {
                printf("You got the secret number correct!");
                scanf("%d", & guess);
            } else if (guess < secretNumber) {
                printf("Enter a higher number: ");
                scanf("%d", & guess);
            } else if (guess > secretNumber) {
                printf("Enter a lower number: ");
                scanf("%d", & guess);
            }
            guessCount = guessCount + 1;
        } else {
            printf("You are out of guesses.");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: oh boy. quite a few issues. I recommend starting afresh. Get a single piece of logic working. Then add another piece. When it works, add another step. Looks like you wrote everything in one step without ensuring you were building on a good foundation. It is imperative to learn good delighting skills. Divide and conquer. Check your Boolean statements. Check your looping. `&& outOfGuesses == 0 ` looks suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you brake the `while` loop before you get to the inner `if`. You should refactor your code so that the correct number check is done only once, before you print `"You got the secret number correct!"`. Something like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){

  int secretNumber = 37;
  int guess;
  int guessCount = 0;
  int guessLimit = 3;
  int outOfGuesses = 0;

  printf("Enter a number between 1 and 100: "); 
  scanf("%d", &guess);
  guessCount = guessCount +1;

  while (guessCount < guessLimit){
    if (guess == secretNumber){
        printf("You got the secret number correct!");
        break;
    }
      
    else if (guess < secretNumber){
        printf("Enter a higher number: ");
        scanf("%d", &guess);
    }
    
    else if (guess > secretNumber){ 
        printf("Enter a lower number: ");
        scanf("%d", &guess);
    }
    guessCount = guessCount + 1;

  }

  if (guessCount == guessLimit){
    printf("You are out of guesses.");
  }

  return 0;
}
```